# Regex Must Match a Word (not to replace) AND a Pattern (to replace) in a Line

Tags: python, regex, string, sed, pcre

With regex (can be PCRE or SED, but can also python[please specify]), I want to remove all occurrences of the lines that contain a single letter comma `(/,.,/g)` and with the word "Labels:"

So for example in these lines:

```
Labels: K,ltemittel,System,j,Vakuum,s
Another tags: a,b,xxx,c,yyy,z
```

to

```
Labels: ltemittel,System,Vakuum
Another tags: a,b,xxx,c,yyy,z
```

What I've tried:

- non-capturing group ("Labels:" still also getting replaced)
- lookahead and lookbehind (cannot use greedy)
- grouping `/(Labels:)*(,.,)` (also capturing the non "Labels:")

Comment: it means either way is ok, in the answer can be specified which regex flavor they're using. it might be useful for others. I'll just remove server because it's vague. thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

You could potentially use:

```
(?i)(^(?!Labels:).*)|\b[a-z],|,[a-z]\b
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wuPvE2/1)

---

- `(?i)` - Set case-insensitive matching 'on';
- `(` - Open 1st capture group;

  - `^` - Start string anchor;
  - `(?!labels:)` - Assert position is not followed by 'Labels:';
  - `.*` - Match (Greedy) 0+ characters other than newline;
  - `)` - Close 1st capture group;
- `|` - Or;
- `\b[a-z],` - Match a word-boundary followed by a single letter and a comma;
- `|` - Or;
- `,[a-z]\b` - Match a comma followed by a single letter and a word-boundary.

Now *replace* it with your **1st** capture group.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/Labels:/s/,[A-Za-z]\>//g;s/\<[A-Za-z],//' input_file
Labels: ltemittel,System,Vakuum
Another tags: a,b,xxx,c,yyy,z
```

Explanation **(Added By Tripleee)**

It looks for a comma, followed by an alphabetic, followed by a word boundary, i.e. the label after the comma is a single letter. Then, it removes any remaining single-letter label immediately before a comma by similar logic

Comment: thanks, this one does the job, but could you give more explanation on the syntax?

Comment: It looks for a comma, followed by an alphabetic, followed by a word boundary, i.e. the label after the comma is a single letter. Then, it removes any remaining single-letter label immediately before a comma by similar logic.

Comment: @Ardhi Please check edit.  tripleee, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Another variation using `gnu-awk`.

For a line that starts with `Labels:` replace a comma followed by a single char a-z or A-Z and a word boundary with an empty string.

```
awk '/^Labels:/{gsub(/,[a-zA-Z]\y|\y[a-zA-Z],/, "")};1' file
```

Output

```
Labels: ltemittel,System,Vakuum
Another tags: a,b,xxx,c,yyy,z
```

---

As you have tagged Python and pcre, another option is to use the `\G` anchor and match `Label:` at the start of the string, and capture in group 1 what you want to keep.

```
(?:^Labels:\h*|\G(?!^))\K(?:([^\s,]{2,}(?:,(?![a-z]$))?)|,?[a-z],?)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/j6lJ61/1) and a [Python demo](https://tio.run/##jVDLSsUwFNznK47BRSLjxceuIMWVyNWV4KYPSDW21b5IUmiv9dtrbltd3wRyZjhnzpDpRle0ze08l3XXGkdG53pgrFPOadPQHRkuwiB9UpmubBAXF1P8IMKzVMp47xsiSmOL5PsGP57BdyJ1eUjOpQzlhHAhCCVn1pmyya1fGDHyh28baY/K6br0dhVeRusxPvGqvvq@huVYh@@b1hXakFO5lyhkGIYBbxjHEYe/oZM24ih@h9PWrY86ln/u6XLVSc5YLTlLGPtoDVkqG9p@Giz6zmMnllB3ts/Elit8rPE1B1nQFdbQd880behRSjbPvw) using the Python [PyPi regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/).

Answer (score 2):

Using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl):

```
perl -lpe 's/(?:,[^,](?=,|$))+//g  if  s/^Labels:\s*\K(?:[^,](?:,|$))*//' file
```

After matching "Labels:" (which is `\K`ept), remove any leading single character items. If that happened, remove all other single character items. This assumes that the "Labels:" part cannot contain single characters separated by commas.

```
$ cat file
Labels: K,ltemittel,a System z,j,Vakuum,s
Another tags: a,b,xxx,c,yyy,z
$ perl -lpe 's/(?:,[^,](?=,|$))+//g  if  s/^Labels:\s*\K(?:[^,](?:,|$))*//' file
Labels: ltemittel,a System z,Vakuum
Another tags: a,b,xxx,c,yyy,z
```

Note: `System` was changed to `a System z` in the above test. Solutions that rely on matching spaces or word boundaries may not deal with this input correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/Labels/{s/( )\S,|(,)\S,|,\S$/\1\2/g;s//\1\2/g}' file
```

If a line contains `Labels`, pattern match for 3 alternate matches and if either the first and second match replace by the matching back reference. Repeat for any overlapping.